# Android windowActionModeOverlay not working in landscape

Tags: android, landscape, android-toolbar, contextual-action-bar, actionmode

I am working on an android app with the toolbar using the support library. I have set

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

in my app style and now my Action Mode overlays properly over the toolbar in portrait mode.

However, when I switch to landscape mode, a little sliver of the tool bar is still seen below my action mode.

[You can see the image of what I'm talking about here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEopy.png)

My toolbar code is pasted below. I include this in all of my activities. I have tried setting the elevation to 0dp but the problem still persists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Menu"
android:elevation="4dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

AppTheme.Menu looks like the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Menu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```